# test fails when i use local library module

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-test

I am using local library with my component (projects), when i do testing getting the following error:

```
1. If 'lib-ibo-library' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        'lib-ibo-library' is not a known element:
        1. If 'lib-ibo-library' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'lib-ibo-library' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<lib-ibo-library></lib-ibo-library>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@0:0
```

here is my module.ts file :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { IboLibraryModule } from 'ibo-library';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        IboLibraryModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my component html file:

`<lib-ibo-library></lib-ibo-library>`

how to fix this? is it require to add even in the parent app?

my ibo library module file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IboLibraryComponent } from './ibo-library.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [IboLibraryComponent],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [IboLibraryComponent]
})
export class IboLibraryModule { }
```

component ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'lib-ibo-library',
    templateUrl: './ibo-library.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./ibo-library.component.scss']
})
export class IboLibraryComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Comment: Can you add the IboLibrary module.ts file?

Comment: @Vinaysharma - library module added

Comment: you are using it in `app-component` only?

Comment: @Sravan - yes. at present

Comment: is `lib-ibo-library` name correct? can you pls paste its component?

Comment: @Sravan - component ts file added, my app running without any issue

Comment: is it working for you now? Is it fixed?

Comment: no,  app is running but not the test. can i share my file if you wish? ( git )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201250/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-sravan).

Comment: Hey @3gwebtrain, In the ibo library spec file, did you instantiated/added/mocked the imports/declarations?